# What is the analogue of Monaco editor's addExtraLib for VSCode extensions?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I need a way to upload type definitions (`d.ts` files) generated at run-time by my tool to editor, so it will be able to make suggestions according to these types.

Files with these types should not be written to file system, or at least should not be visible for a user. The way my tool works is some "magic" happens in background and user is able to use modules generated under the hood, and the editor provides types for these modules.

In Monaco editor it is possible by using the `monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib` API method ([Documentation link](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/typedoc/interfaces/languages.typescript.LanguageServiceDefaults.html#addExtraLib)).

I'm trying to migrate my tool to a VSCode extension.
Is there any way to add in-memory type definitions for ts files via VSCode extensions?

I tried to find some examples or issues in VSCode GitHub, there were a couple of similar questions, but no answers.